# Calculating the number of samples in a WAV file

Tags: audio, wav

I am currently looking at online examples and here is a WAV file contents in bytes

**52 49 46 46 24 08 00 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 10 00 00 00 01 00 02 00 
22 56 00 00 88 58 01 00 04 00 10 00 64 61 74 61 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 
24 17 1e f3 3c 13 3c 14 16 f9 18 f9 34 e7 23 a6 3c f2 24 f2 11 ce 1a 0d**

and here is the visual; representation:

[image]

So according to the Subchunk2Size there is 2048 bytes in the data. The formula to calculate the number of samples in a WAV is given as:

```
Subchunk2Size /(NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8 ) = NumSamples
```

If I plugin numbers and according to the information given I get NumSamples = 512. But in the diagram the sample rate is 22050. How can the total number fo samples be less than a single second of samples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those wondering, here is a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20141213140451/https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) to the source.

I suspect they are just using a bad example where the duration of the wav file would be less than a second. Their formula makes sense and we can use it to verify the data size of a one second wav file.

If our sample rate is 22050 samples/sec and our wav file is one second, then numSamples  = 22050. We know that Subchunk2Size is the number of bytes in the data and can be calculated using this formula: `Subchunk2Size = numSamples * numChannels * bitsPerSample / 8` , so, assuming numChannels = 2 and bitsPerSample = 16, we know that a one second wav file should be `(22050 * 2 * 16 / 8) bytes` which is `88200 bytes`, so it would make sense that if Subchunk2Size is 2048 bytes, as per the website's example, then the duration of the wav file would be less than a second and thus, numSamples would be less than 22050.